# What would be the outcome if a quantum measurement has macroscopic consequences?

Tags: measurement

Suppose there are n qubits each in the state $|+\rangle$ with equal probability of measurement as 0 and 1.
Set up a measurement of each qubit such that if we measure 1 it triggers a nuke which blows up the entire globe killing everyone on the planet.

If we do this experiment, what would be the actual outcome? Since measuring any of the qubits as 1 would spell doom for every conscious observer, would we actually measure a 1 or would we measure all the qubits as 0?

Comment: My take is that superposition of possible outcomes seems no more mysterious than dice-throwing. Before throwing a dice, there is also superposition of outcomes $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$; it doesn't mean that all of those possible outcomes "exist" somehow even before the dice is thrown. Once we throw the dice, than exactly 1 single outcome will emerge, and it doesn't mean that those unrealized outcome have somehow "collapsed" as a result. In this way, I feel that superposition is just a statement of probabilites. So in your case, I don't think we are in a state of both alive & dead before measurement

Comment: This has been called Everettian computation or an anthropic computer; you can also search "PostBQP" for some other information.  But, I agree with the commenters and other answers that there's nothing "quantum" in the way you framed it, as your setup is equivalent to a bunch of Hadamard gates but without any further phase kick-back or interference.  Another interesting related gedanken-experiment that actually *has* been put to practice and that actually *does* rely on interference is the "Elitzur-Vaidman Bomb Tester" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%E2%80%93Vaidman_bomb_tester).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that qubits are independent, the outcome is same as tossing $n$ fair coins. With probability of 50% you measure outcome 1 for each qubit. Probability that you measure all qubits in state 0 (i.e. the nuke is not triggered) is $1/2^n$.

Concerning second paragraph of your question, there is no influence of your wish to avoid the nuke exploding as qubits are not entangled with your mind. It is generally more or less sci-fi to assume that you can entangled a mind with a quantum system.